# Setting Proxy Using Command Prompt Failure Via Python

Tags: python, cmd.exe, proxy, ip

According to some of the blogs (including StackOverflow), I was trying to set proxy using cmd (run as admin). I am trying to do this via Python.
Note:

- `1234` is used here as a mask to my current IP.
- `5678` is used here as a mask to the Proxy IP i am trying to connect to.

Here is what and how I tried:

1. I viewed my initial status.

```
#In cmd:
>netsh winhttp show proxy
Direct Access (no proxy server)

#In google chrome:
> ip address
1234 your public ip address
```

2. Now I connected to Proxy IP using python. This is my code:

```
import win32com.shell.shell as shell
command = 'netsh winhttp set proxy '+'5678'
shell.ShellExecuteEx(lpVerb='runas', lpFile='cmd.exe', lpParameters='/c '+command)
```

3. Then I check my settings via cmd.

```
#In cmd:
>netsh winhttp show proxy
Proxy Server(s) : 5678
```

Now here is the problem. when I checked my IP using Google, it showed:

```
#In google chrome:
> ip address
1234 your public ip address
```

the same IP.

Why is it so? Why was I unsuccessful? How do I succeed?

PS. I found a solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51554453/13062813but) but i am not sure how to implement that on python.

Comment: WinHTTP and WinINet have nothing to do with each other. Browsers use WinINet. Programmers use WinHTTP which is faster but doesn't support many of the WinINet features essential to browsing..

Comment: So then how do I do that via command prompt?

Comment: `netsh winsock` WinINet is a winsock implementation. You used to (early 90s) have to buy one to access the internet till MS included their own in Windows. WinHTTP is meant for servers to contact other foreign web servers, and their is also a server one (even faster but less featured) for contacting a server next to you in your farm.

Comment: netsh winsock doesn't have any proxy settings

Comment: @αԋɱҽԃαмєяιcαη so after setting the proxy, i need to excecute `netsh winhttp import proxy source =ie` too? but doesnt that import proxy. i need to set proxy. I really am doing this via python using `import win32com.shell.shell as shell`

Comment: @JoshuaVarghese https://www.scrapehero.com/how-to-rotate-proxies-and-ip-addresses-using-python-3/

Comment: @αԋɱҽԃαмєяιcαη i'k that. I want to use that proxy for windows using cmd, like a vpn (i know what a vpn is). I want to set proxy of computer via cmd

Comment: @αԋɱҽԃαмєяιcαη I've found a solution https://stackoverflow.com/a/51554453/13062813but how do i do that using python winreg?

Comment: @αԋɱҽԃαмєяιcαη i'll let you the bounty if you could convert it

Comment: @Mark do you know to convert a code to python> see above comments